# Google Assistant App Actions codelab example not working (Fit Actions) on AndroidTV

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

I'm trying out this example:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appactions/#0

I've built the app & installed it on my AndroidTV device, and able to launch it via:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://fit-actions.firebaseapp.com/start"
```

but, when I try to run the App Actions Test Tool and try out the suggested actions.intent.START_EXERCISE intent (which is supposedly integrated with the Google Assistant), I just see an error that says, "You don't have an app that can do this". The entire command looks like this:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/00001f0ad064c9a0?intent=actions.intent.START_EXERCISE\&param.exercise=%7B%0A++++%22%40type%22%3A+%22Exercise%22%2C%0A++++%22name%22%3A+%22Running%22%2C%0A++++%22%40context%22%3A+%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.googleapis.com%22%0A%7D"
```

Also, I tried directly speaking the request, "Hey Google, start running in Fit Actions", but I get the same error. Any ideas what could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that AppActions is not supported on AndroidTV, I tried this example on a Samsung tablet and the test tool launches it just fine. That said, it's still not working when tried with a voice command